# Weak stationarity of continuous ARMA process from Brockwell

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, arima, stationarity, stochastic-integral

I am currently working on Brockwell ["Levy-driven CARMA processes"](https://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/053_1_0113.pdf) (2001) and I am stuck in the introduction.
So we have a continuous AR process (CAR(p))
\begin{align*}
    X_t=e^{At}X_0+\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-u)}e dB_u\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \Leftrightarrow X_t=e^{A(t-s)}X_s+\int_{s}^{t}e^{A(t-u)}edB_u, \ \ \text{for} \ \ t>s\geq 0
\end{align*}
where $A$ is a matrix, $e$ a vector and $B_u$ a multidimensional standard Brownian motion.
**Statement to prove:**

> Brockwell states that the necessary and sufficient conditions for stationarity of the process $X_t$ are that the eigenvalues of $A$ all have negative real parts and the distribution of $X_0$ has mean $  E (X_0)=0$ and covariance matrix $E (X_{0}X_0^T)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{Au} \mathbf{e}_p \mathbf{e}_p^T e^{A^Tu}du$.

**My attempt:**
My idea is to extend the stochastic integral to the negative half-line. To extend the standard Brownian motion $B$, we define a new process $B^0$ with two independent standard Brownian motions $B^1$ and $B^2$ by
\begin{align*}
    B^0(t)=B^1(t) 1_{\{t\in [0, \infty) \}}- B^2(-t-)1_{\{t\in (-\infty,0] \}}, \ \ t \in R.
\end{align*}
Now the extended process $\{X_t, \ t\in R\}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
    X_t=e^{A(t-s)}X_s+\int_{s}^{t}e^{A(t-u)}edB^0_u, \ \ t>s, \ \text{with} \ s\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
Since the eigenvalues of $A$ all have negative real parts, letting $s\rightarrow -\infty$ gives us
\begin{align*}
    X_t=\int_{-\infty}^{t}e^{A(t-u)}edB^0_u,
\end{align*}
which has the same distribution as
\begin{align*}
    \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{Au}edB^0_u.
\end{align*}
Now with the extended process $X_t$ I am able to calculate the correct expected value and convariance.

**My question:**
Can I extend the process to prove the statement or is that not possible?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your write *So we have a continuous ARMA process (CAR(p))*. The acronym does not seem to match the title. Should it perhaps be CARMA(p,q)? Or continuous AR process?

Comment: Hi: The explanation is here but it looks like it will take some slow and careful reading. good luck. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414909000295 Note that I got  lucky because it's very difficult to get pdfs from science direct.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Richard Hardy it should be the state equation of a CARMA(p,q) process with p>q.

Comment: @markleeds I have seen this paper. But i also came across this one https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1097608/file.pdf (page 3), where they use my mehtod but with a generel Levy process. So can i adapt the procedure to a Brownian motion?

Comment: Hi: I don't totally see what you're doing with the extended process but, if you do, then my confusion obviously doesn't matter.  The line that confuses me is : Now the extended process is given by". But you don't need to waste your time explaining that to me. If you can get the answer using both approaches, then that would be the ideal thing because that says that you REALLY understand what's going on.

Comment: I glanced at paper but  that would take me days ( maybe weeks ) of careful reading and, even then, I don't know if I'd understand it. If you're REALLY interested in a specific question about that paper, it might be helpful to cross post on math.stackexchange but mention that you already posted on quant.stackexchange and ask a specific question about your confusion.